# AWS Command Line querying for EC2 Describe Network Interfaces that are available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-programming

Been searching around and playing around with the aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces command...
Can't seem to get a specific query to work.

Wanted to retrieve a list of ENI's that are currently with the status: available.

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=Status,Values=available --query 'length(NetworkInterfaces)'
```

Tried the command above, and output an error. Probably due to no structure of Name=Status.

Comment: `Status` should be lowercase: `status`.

Comment: Thanks Jordan! Out of curiosity... I'm trying to retrieve a list of interfaces Ids by running this command... seems like its giving me a null.. am I missing a param here?


aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=status,Values=available --query "NetworkInterfaces[*].NetworkInterfaceId"

Comment: removed the asterisk within the [*] and it produced the result!